# hidden attribute ignored on Button component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to hide a Material-UI `Button` component by adding the `hidden` attribute, but it appears the attribute is ignored. I've used the `hidden` attribute on other Material-UI components such as `Typography`, `Grid` and `Box` and there it works fine. Below is a simplified snippet of my code. [Click here to try it out on CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-yprld?file=/demo.tsx)

```
<Typography hidden={loading}>
  Works. This text is not displayed when `loading` is truthy.
</Typography>
<Button hidden={loading}>
  Doesn't work. This Button is still there!
</Button >
```

Comment: https://material-ui.com/api/button/ It does not have hidden prop. I'd suggest conditional rendering.

Comment: @MindaugasNakrosis neither [material-ui.com/api/typography](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#props) has a `hidden` prop. While I do agree with your suggestion of using conditional rendering, it would still be interesting to understand why the two components behave differently.

Comment: Both components inherit their `hidden` prop from `HTMLAttributes`, along with a bunch of other standard props like `id`, `style`, `className`, etc. Am I not supposed to use these properties?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TLDR**: Don't use the `hidden` attribute. Use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) like `{loading && <Component/>}` or a style like `<Component style={{ display: loading ? 'none' : undefined }} />`

First, the `hidden` attribute has nothing to do with Material UI or React, but is a default HTML attribute from the web standard. Second, the `hidden` attribute is overridden if a `display: ...` style is applied to the same element. It doesn't matter if these styles are inline or coming from CSS. As a result, the `hidden` attribute is "ignored" by any Material-UI component that happens to set the `display` attribute.

You can try this on any of the examples from the official docs. For example, playing around with [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stnfx) you can see `hidden` work on `Card`, `CardContent` and `Typography`, but ignored on `CardActionArea`, `CardMedia`, `CardActions` and `Button`.

Considering the above it's best to avoid the `hidden` attribute as its behavior is different on a per-component basis. Moreover, if in any next version of Material UI a component is updated to use `display` internally, it'll change the semantics of `hidden` for that component and break stuff in your code base.